# How to read .evtx file using python?

Tags: python, logging, event-log

Guys do anyone know how to read event log file in C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs with .evtx extension?
I have already tried to open it using notepad and read using python but notepad says access is denied...
Do anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance..

Comment: There is a module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-evtx/0.5.0 maybe give this a try

Comment: If access is denied, are you sure you are running your script at the right priv level?  For example, your right click open with notepad will run it at lowest priv unless you UAC first.  Try running notepad as admin, then opening the file from the file->open menu.  You shouldn't get access denied.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would read the file "Forwarded Events" from the event viewer. You need admin access so I would run it as admin but I it will prompt you for a password if you don't.

```
import win32evtlog
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ctypes
import sys


def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():


    # open event file
    query_handle = win32evtlog.EvtQuery(
        'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\ForwardedEvents.evtx',
        win32evtlog.EvtQueryFilePath)

    read_count = 0
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        a += 1
        # read 1 record(s)
        events = win32evtlog.EvtNext(query_handle, 1)
        read_count += len(events)
        # if there is no record break the loop
        if len(events) == 0:
            break

        for event in events:
            xml_content = win32evtlog.EvtRender(event, win32evtlog.EvtRenderEventXml)
            # parse xml content
            xml = ET.fromstring(xml_content)


            # xml namespace, root element has a xmlns definition, so we have to use the namespace
            ns = '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}'

            substatus = xml[1][9].text

            event_id = xml.find(f'.//{ns}EventID').text
            computer = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Computer').text
            channel = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Channel').text
            execution = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Execution')
            process_id = execution.get('ProcessID')
            thread_id = execution.get('ThreadID')
            time_created = xml.find(f'.//{ns}TimeCreated').get('SystemTime')
            #data_name = xml.findall('.//EventData')
            #substatus = data_name.get('Data')
            #print(substatus)

            event_data = f'Time: {time_created}, Computer: {computer}, Substatus: {substatus}, Event Id: {event_id}, Channel: {channel}, Process Id: {process_id}, Thread Id: {thread_id}'
            print(event_data)

            user_data = xml.find(f'.//{ns}UserData')
            # user_data has possible any data

      

else:
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)

input()
```

Answer (score 0):

`.evtx` is the extension for Windows Eventlog files. It contains data in a special binary format designed by Microsoft so you cannot simply open it in a text editor.

The are open source tools to read .evtx and the [NXLog EE](https://nxlog.co/products/nxlog-enterprise-edition) can also read .evtx files. (Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the latter).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the accepted answer a bit as following, so it becomes reusable:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et
import win32evtlog
from collections import namedtuple

class EventLogParser:
def __init__(self, exported_log_file):
    self.exported_log_file = exported_log_file

def get_all_events(self):
    windows_events = []
    query_handle = win32evtlog.EvtQuery(str(self.exported_log_file),
        win32evtlog.EvtQueryFilePath | win32evtlog.EvtQueryReverseDirection)
    while True:
        raw_event_collection = win32evtlog.EvtNext(query_handle, 1)
        if len(raw_event_collection) == 0:
            break
        for raw_event in raw_event_collection:
            windows_events.append(self.parse_raw_event(raw_event))
    return windows_events

def parse_raw_event(self, raw_event):
    xml_content = win32evtlog.EvtRender(raw_event, win32evtlog.EvtRenderEventXml)
    root = Et.fromstring(xml_content)
    ns =  "{" + root.tag.split('}')[0].strip('{') + "}"
    system = root.find(f'{ns}System')
    event_id = system.find(f'{ns}EventID').text
    level = system.find(f'{ns}Level').text
    time_created = system.find(f'{ns}TimeCreated').get('SystemTime')
    computer = system.find(f'{ns}Computer').text
    WindowsEvent = namedtuple('WindowsEvent',
        'event_id, level, time_created, computer')
    return WindowsEvent(event_id, level, time_created, computer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the "python-evtx" library, you can install it using this command:

- pip install python-evtx

In my case, I'm not interested in reading records with the "Information" level.

```
import os
import codecs
from lxml import etree
import Evtx.Evtx as evtx

def evtxFile(absolutePath, filenameWithExt, ext, _fromDate, _toDate):
    print("Reading: " + filenameWithExt)

    outText = ""
    channel = ""

    #read the windows event viewer log and convert its contents to XML
    with codecs.open(tempFilePath, "a+", "utf-8", "ignore") as tempFile:
        with evtx.Evtx(absolutePath) as log:
            for record in log.records():
                xmlLine = record.xml()
                xmlLine = xmlLine.replace(" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event\"", "")
                xmlParse = etree.XML(xmlLine)
                level = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//Level/text()")

                if not level == "0" and not level == "4":
                    providerName = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//Provider/@Name")
                    qualifiers = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//EventID/@Qualifiers")
                    timestamp = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//TimeCreated/@SystemTime")
                    eventID = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//EventID/text()")
                    task = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//Task/text()")
                    keywords = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//Keywords/text()")
                    eventRecordID = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//EventRecordID/text()")
                    channel = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//Channel/text()")
                    computer = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//Computer/text()")
                    message = parseXMLtoString(xmlParse, ".//Data/text()")

                    if level == "1":
                        level = "Critical"
                    elif level == "2":
                        level = "Error"
                    elif level == "3":
                        level = "Warning"
                                
                    date = timestamp[0:10]
                    time = timestamp[11:19]
                    time = time.replace(".", "")

                    _date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                                        
                    if _fromDate <= _date <= _toDate:

                        message = message.replace("<string>", "")
                        message = message.replace("</string>", "")
                        message = message.replace("\r\n", " ")
                        message = message.replace("\n\r", " ")
                        message = message.replace("\n", " ")
                        message = message.replace("\r", " ")
                                    
                        outText = date + " " + time + "|" + level + "|" + message.strip() + "|" + task + "|" + computer + "|" + providerName + "|" + qualifiers + "|" + eventID + "|" + eventRecordID + "|" + keywords + "\n"

                        tempFile.writelines(outText)

    with codecs.open(tempFilePath, "r", "utf-8", "ignore") as tempFile2:
        myLinesFromDateRange = tempFile2.readlines()
            
    #delete the temporary file that was created
    os.remove(tempFilePath)          

    if len(myLinesFromDateRange) > 0:
        createFolder("\\filtered_data_files\\")
        outFilename = "windows_" + channel.lower() + "_event_viewer_logs" + ext

        myLinesFromDateRange.sort()
        #remove duplicate records from the list
        myFinalLinesFromDateRange = list(set(myLinesFromDateRange))
        myFinalLinesFromDateRange.sort()

        with codecs.open(os.getcwd() + "\\filtered_data_files\\" + outFilename, "a+", "utf-8", "ignore") as linesFromDateRange:
            linesFromDateRange.seek(0)
            if len(linesFromDateRange.read(100)) > 0:
                linesFromDateRange.writelines("\n")
            linesFromDateRange.writelines(myFinalLinesFromDateRange)
        del myLinesFromDateRange[:]
        del myFinalLinesFromDateRange[:]
    else:
        print("No data was found within the specified date range.")

    print("Closing: " + filenameWithExt)
```

I hope it helps you or someone else in the future.

EDIT:
The "tempFilePath" can be anything you want, for example:

```
tempFilePath = os.getcwd() + "\\tempFile.txt"
```

I collected some information first before calling the "evtxFile" function:
The "From" and the "To" dates are in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD

Converted the dates to "date" data type:

```
_fromDate = datetime.strptime(fromDate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
_toDate = datetime.strptime(toDate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Divided the directory where the .evtx files are located into different parts:

```
def splitDirectory(root, file):
    absolutePathOfFile = os.path.join(root, file)
    filePathWithoutFilename = os.path.split(absolutePathOfFile)[0]
    filenameWithExt = os.path.split(absolutePathOfFile)[1]
    filenameWithoutExt = os.path.splitext(filenameWithExt)[0]
    extension = os.path.splitext(filenameWithExt)[1]

return absolutePathOfFile, filePathWithoutFilename, filenameWithExt, filenameWithoutExt, extension

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for f in files:
        absolutePathOfFile, filePathWithoutFilename, filenameWithExt, 
filenameWithoutExt, extension = splitDirectory(root, f)

        if extension == ".evtx":
            evtxFile(absolutePathOfFile, filenameWithExt, ".txt", _fromDate, _toDate)
```

Comment: Could you please share how to use your function? I'm struggling with the .evtx files and your function is looking as if it will be the most universal but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: I tried calling it both ways: evtxFile(r'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx','Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx','.extv','2022-12-04','2022-12-08') and evtxFile(r'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs','Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx','.extv','2022-12-04','2022-12-08')

Comment: + I can't see 'tempFilePath' defined anywhere in the code

Comment: @Ulewsky I'm so sorry for the late reply. I added the missing information. I think I didn't miss anything this time.